# VS Windows Phone Lookup and Select Contact

Tags: windows-phone

How can I make a drop down box for someone to select one of their contacts from? I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is built in functionality. Use the `PhoneNumberChooserTask`

```
//When you see the red underline hold (control + period) 
// OR you can just add the using yourself at the top of the page
//using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
PhoneNumberChooserTask pnct= new PhoneNumberChooserTask(); 

pnct.Completed += new EventHandler<PhoneNumberResult>(pnct_Completed);
```

Once you have it initialized you can do a show

```
pnct.Show();
```

Then in the completed event just extract what you need.

```
void pnct_Completed(object sender, PhoneNumberResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The phone number for " + e.DisplayName + " is " + e.PhoneNumber);

        //Code to start a new call using the retrieved phone number.
        //PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();
        //phoneCallTask.DisplayName = e.DisplayName;
        //phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = e.PhoneNumber;
        //phoneCallTask.Show();
    }
}
```

This is the suggested way of doing what you are asking because it keeps the environment consistent for the user. A consistent user environment means they will be happier with your app.

The reference for this answer can be found on this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394021%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I mean what do I add it in? Grid etc

Comment: You don't have to add it to anything. Put this in your back end code. Its already built for you. The Show() method call will show all their contacts.